# Where did all the negative potential energy in gluons went to?

Tags: standard-model, potential-energy, quarks, gluons, quark-gluon-plasma

I have watched [PBS Space Time that gluons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo232kyTsO0) could be viewed as negative potential energy (tension between quarks) and that they actually are 99% of all the mass in protons and neutrons.

Now the way I understand negative potential energy is like 'borrowing' it from somewhere and using it up and then if you want to get to zero value state you need to add energy to get there, since to get to negative potential that energy had to used by something.  Example would be when gas that got compressed and turned hot, but that energy was used so it cooled down to room temperature and then if uncompressed it freezes because energy is gone.

**So what was it that took all that gluon energy and used it up (where did it go)?

Or am I misunderstanding this?**

Comment: Smash a proton against another proton, so you pumped the system full of extra kinetic energy. What you get out is the original protons (usually) plus lots of extra particles but less fast. The extra energy went into the mass of these extra particles, and since they are mostly hadrons, into that of their roiling gluons inside of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and that they actually are 99% of all the mass in protons and neutrons.

That is where all that energy is, by the special relativity equation , all the constituents add up [to one four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) which has as a "length" the mass of the proton.

Your question then becomes where do the protons come from, and in the [mainstream history of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg) they came when the universe expanded enough to cool and allow protons to form by 1μsecond from the beginning. Before that the universe  was [a quark gluon plasma](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/unify.html#c1).

Comment: Hello anna, it just 'hit' me... so the universe was like a 'cold gas' (from my example) at the end of [inflatory epoch](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/unify.html#c1) that then 'sucked' the energy  into gluons, that then formed the protons and neutrons... Or is it just called negative potential energy because it is convenient for calculations?

Comment: Negative and positive potential energy are a matter of convention, and one has to stick to it. The "cold" comes from the expansion, more space and the soup cools. symmetry breaks with the Higgs mechanism and particles acquire mass and can fall into the bound states of proton and neutron.  The energy of the "fall" would reheat the soup except that space is still expanding. I just wanted to point out that all energy we observe now as kinetic or mass  comes from the original creation of the universe.